# Java - How do I convert a string of letters into an array with the corresponding numerical values?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How can I easily convert the following string into an array of integers with the corresponding numerical values (i.e. a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, etc):

```
String plaintext = "sallywenttotheseashoretocollectseashellsxx";
```

Comment: You want to convert each character to a digit? Or do you want a map that connects an integer to a character?

Comment: Yes, so that "s" would go to 18, "a" would go to 0, etc

Comment: what about upper/lower case is 'a' == 'A' == 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for lower case only:

```
int[] string_to_numbers = new int[s.length()];

for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
    string_to_numbers[i] = s.charAt(i)-'a';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question as stated is poorly defined, but here's what you could do:

```
char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
int[] results = new int[text.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) { 
    //your poorly defined conversion
    results[i] = someOperation(chars[i])
}
.
.
// a best guess at what this function would do
private static int someOperation(char c) { 
   return (c - 'a');
}
```

If the letter `a` maps to 0, what does the letter `A` map to?

Comment: Problem is "into an array", so a skeleton (which I approve of) should likely use a standard for-loop and show creation of the result array.

Comment: I'm confined to only using lowercase in this program.

Answer (score 1):

We can start with the identity you've given 'a' = 0, that means we can just subtract 'a' from any given character. That is something like,

```
String plaintext = "sallywenttotheseashoretocollectseashellsxx";
char[] letterArray = plaintext.toCharArray();
int[] array = new int[letterArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < letterArray.length; i++) {
    array[i] = letterArray[i] - 'a';
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output is (formatted for this post)

```
[18, 0, 11, 11, 24, 22, 4, 13, 19, 19, 14, 19, 7, 4, 18, 4, 0, 18, 7, 14, 17, 4,
 19, 14, 2, 14, 11, 11, 4, 2, 19, 18, 4, 0, 18, 7, 4, 11, 11, 18, 23, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deduct the character `'a'` from the character itself so that would give 0 for `'a'`, 1 for `'b'` etc.

```
int[] digits = new int[plaintext.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    digits[i] = plaintext.charAt(i) - 'a';
}
```

**NOTE:** this will only work for lowercase letters

Answer (score 0):

```
String plaintext = "sallywenttotheseashoretocollectseashellsxx";
        int arr[] = new int[plaintext.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<plaintext.length();i++){
            arr[i]= plaintext.charAt(i)-96;
        }
```

you can convert your text to lowercase, in case it may also have uppercase letters

Answer (score 0):

Just `-a` or `ASCII` value of `a(97)`. You can try this

```
public class ASCII {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String plaintext = "sallywenttotheseashoretocollectseashellsxx";
        int a_code[]; 
        a_code = new int[plaintext.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++){
            a_code[i] = plaintext.charAt(i) - 'a'; //plaintext.charAt(i) - 97;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++){
            System.out.println(a_code[i]);
        }
    }
}
```